# How can I allowed a global AudioPlayer component to play the podcast selected from the children Info component, in REACT?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I create an application where on the homepage each tile correspond to a podcast, once you click on the tile you are routed to the specific info of that podcast. At the moment, once the website is open, the audioplayer start to play the latest podcast and you can switch to the next one or the previous one through the icon on it.
Once I get into the info component of a tile, I would like to click play and update the audioplayer playing the corresponding podcast, updating also the order of the player (if  form the info component i am playing the podcast nr. 11, the prev should be the 10 and the next the 12, and so on).
I store the data for each podcast locally on a file data.json.

data.json

```
    [
  {
    "id": "001",
    "title": "001",
    "cover": "/images/1.png",
    "info": "1st podcast",
    "file_podcast": "/podcast/001.mp3"
  },
  {
    "id": "002",
    "title": "002",
    "cover": "/images/2.png",
    "info": "2nd podcast",
    "file_podcast": "/podcast/002.mp3"
  },
  {
    "id": "003",
    "title": "003",
    "cover": "/images/3.png",
    "info": "3rd podcast",
    "file_podcast": "/podcast/RadioCircolo003.mp3"
  }]
```

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import Home from "./components/Home";
import About from "./pages/About";
import Info from "./components/Info";
import { Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar";
import Footer from "./components/Footer";
import AudioPlayer1 from "./components/AudioPlayer1";
import data from "./data/data.json";

function App() {
  
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-col min-h-screen">
      <Navbar />
      <div className="flex-grow">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/about" element={<About />} />
          <Route path="/:title" element={<Info />} />
        </Routes>
        <AudioPlayer1 file={data} />
      </div>
      <Footer />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Home.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import Info from "./Info";
import Tiles from "./Tiles";
import data from "../data/data";

const Home = () => {
  const [info, setInfo] = useState(null);

  return (
    <div className="m-5">
      {/* {info ? (
        <Info info={info} backToTiles={() => setInfo(null)} />
      ) : (
        <Tiles data={data} setInfo={setInfo} info={info} />
      )} */}
       <Tiles data={data} setInfo={setInfo} info={info} />

    </div>
  );
};

export default Home;
```

AudioPlayer1.js

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useEffect, useCallback } from "react";
import {
  AiFillBackward,
  AiFillForward,
  // AiFillFastBackward,
  // AiFillFastForward,
  AiOutlinePlayCircle,
  AiOutlinePause,
} from "react-icons/ai";

const AudioPlayer1 = ({ file }) => {
  console.log(file);
  const lastPodcastIndex = file.length - 1;
  const [activePodcast, setActivePodcast] = useState(
    file[lastPodcastIndex].file_podcast
  );
  const [activePodcastName, setActivePodcastName] = useState(
    file[lastPodcastIndex].title
  );
  const [isPlaying, setIsPlaying] = useState(false);
  const [duration, setDuration] = useState(0);
  const [currentTime, setCurrentTime] = useState(0);

  // ref to audio element
  const audioPlayer = useRef();

  // ref to progress bar
  const progressBar = useRef();

  // ref to animation prgress bar
  const animationRef = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    const audio = audioPlayer.current;
    
    // Set the active podcast source and load it
    audio.src = activePodcast;
    audio.load();

    const handleLoadedMetadata = () => {
      // Set the duration and maximum value of the progress bar
      const seconds = Math.floor(audio.duration);
      setDuration(seconds);
      progressBar.current.max = seconds;
    };

    audio.addEventListener("loadedmetadata", handleLoadedMetadata);

    return () => {
      audio.removeEventListener("loadedmetadata", handleLoadedMetadata);
    };
  }, [activePodcast]);

  const calculateTime = (time) => {
    if (typeof time == "undefined") return "00:00:00";
    const hours = Math.floor(time / 3600);
    const returnedHours = hours < 10 ? `0${hours}` : `${hours}`;
    // need to take off the hours we have already counted
    const minutes = Math.floor(time / 60 - hours * 60);
    const returnedMinutes = minutes < 10 ? `0${minutes}` : `${minutes}`;
    const seconds = Math.floor(time % 60);
    const returnedSeconds = seconds < 10 ? `0${seconds}` : `${seconds}`;
    return `${returnedHours}:${returnedMinutes}:${returnedSeconds}`;
  };

  const togglePlayPause = () => {
    const prevValue = isPlaying;
    setIsPlaying(!prevValue);
    console.log(prevValue);
    if (prevValue) {
      console.log(audioPlayer.current);
      audioPlayer.current.play();
      animationRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(whilePlaying);
    } else {
      audioPlayer.current.pause();
      cancelAnimationFrame(animationRef.current);
    }
  };

   // Update progress bar and current time while playing
  const whilePlaying = useCallback(() => {
    progressBar.current.value = audioPlayer.current.currentTime;
    setCurrentTime(progressBar.current.value);
    animationRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(whilePlaying);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    const player = audioPlayer.current;

    const handleCanPlayThrough = () => {
      setIsPlaying(true);
      player.play();
      animationRef.current = requestAnimationFrame(whilePlaying);
    };

    player.addEventListener("canplaythrough", handleCanPlayThrough);

    return () => {
      player.removeEventListener("canplaythrough", handleCanPlayThrough);
      player.pause();
      cancelAnimationFrame(animationRef.current);
    };
  }, [whilePlaying]);

  const changeRange = () => {
    audioPlayer.current.currentTime = progressBar.current.value;
    setCurrentTime(progressBar.current.value);
  };

  const handlePrevPodcast = () => {
    const currentIndex = file.findIndex(
      (item) => item.file_podcast === activePodcast
    );
    if (currentIndex - 1 < 0) {
      setActivePodcast(file[file.length - 1].file_podcast);
      setActivePodcastName(file[file.length - 1].title);
      setDuration(file[file.length - 1].duration);
      setIsPlaying(false);
    } else {
      setActivePodcast(file[currentIndex - 1].file_podcast);
      setActivePodcastName(file[currentIndex - 1].title);
      setDuration(file[currentIndex - 1].duration);
      setIsPlaying(false);
    }
  };

  const handleNextPodcast = () => {
    const currentIndex = file.findIndex(
      (item) => item.file_podcast === activePodcast
    );
    if (currentIndex < file.length - 1) {
      setActivePodcast(file[currentIndex + 1].file_podcast);
      setActivePodcastName(file[currentIndex + 1].title);
      setDuration(file[currentIndex + 1].duration);
      setIsPlaying(false);
    } else {
      setActivePodcast(file[0].file_podcast);
      setActivePodcastName(file[0].title);
      setDuration(file[0].duration);
    }
  };

  return (
   <div className="flex flex-col md:flex-row items-center bg-[#ffffffdd] sticky bottom-0 z-10 overflow-hidden top-0">
  <audio ref={audioPlayer} src={activePodcast} preload="metadata" />
  <div className="flex items-center pt-3 pb-3 md:pt-0 md:pb-0">
    <button className="player_buttons ml-0 md:ml-10" onClick={handlePrevPodcast}>
      <AiFillBackward className="player_icons rounded-lg" />
    </button>
    <button className="player_buttons mx-2 md:ml-0 md:mr-0" onClick={togglePlayPause}>
      {!isPlaying ? (
        <AiOutlinePause className="player_icons rounded-lg" />
      ) : (
        <AiOutlinePlayCircle className="player_icons rounded-lg" />
      )}
    </button>
    <button className="player_buttons md:ml-0 md:mr-2" onClick={handleNextPodcast}>
      <AiFillForward className="player_icons rounded-lg" />
    </button>
  </div>

  <div className="flex items-center flex-grow">
    {/* current time */}
    <div className="px-2 font-bold text-[#161414dd] w-[100px] hidden md:block">
      {calculateTime(currentTime)}
    </div>

    {/* progress bar */}
    <div className="flex items-center flex-col-reverse md:flex-col pb-0 md:pb-6 flex-grow max-w-full">
      <label htmlFor="title" className="text-sm font-bold text-[#161414dd] my-1">
        #{activePodcastName}
      </label>
      <input
        type="range"
        className="progressBar h-1 rounded-lg cursor-pointer range-sm accent-[#161414dd] -webkit-apperance-none max-w-full"
        defaultValue="0"
        ref={progressBar}
        onChange={changeRange}
      />
    </div>

    {/* duration */}
    <div className="px-2 font-bold mr-10 text-[#161414dd] w-[100px] hidden md:block">
      {duration && !isNaN(duration) && calculateTime(duration)}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  );
};

export default AudioPlayer1;
```

Tiles.js

```
import React from "react";
import { NavLink } from "react-router-dom";

const Tiles = ({ data, setInfo }) => {

  return (
    <>
      <div className="grid grid-cols-1 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-4 gap-3 mt-5">
        {data &&
          data
            .slice(0)
            .reverse()
            .map((item) => {
              return (
                <NavLink to=
                  {{pathname: `/${item.title}`}}
                  state=
                  {{ from: item }}
                  key={item.id}>
                <div
                  key={item.id}
                  onClick={() => setInfo(item)}
                  className="relative block group w-full h-full aspect-square"
                >
                  <img
                    alt={item.title}
                    src={`${item.cover}`}
                    className="h-full w-full group-hover:opacity-50 inset-0 object-cover absolute cursor-pointer"
                    title={item.title}
                  />

                  <div className="relative p-5 cursor-pointer">
                    <div className="mt-60">
                      <div className="transition-all transform translate-y-8 opacity-0 group-hover:opacity-100 group-hover:translate-y-0 bg-[#161414] border-white ">
                        <p className="text-white p-2 text-2xl font-bold">
                          #{item.title}
                        </p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </NavLink>
              );
            })}
      </div>
    </>
  );
};

export default Tiles;
```

Info.js

```
    import React, { useState } from "react";
import { AiOutlineArrowLeft, AiOutlinePlayCircle } from "react-icons/ai";
// import AudioPlayer from "./AudioPlayer";
import { NavLink, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const Info = () => {
  // const [isShow, setIsShow] = useState(false);
  const location = useLocation();
  const { state } = location;

  console.log(state.from);

  // const showPlayer = () => {
  //   setIsShow(!isShow);
  // };

  console.log();

  const trackList = state.from.trackList;
  const members = state.from.members;

  // const slug = title.replace(/-/g, " ");

  return (
    <div key={state.from.id} className="mt-5 mx-4 md:mx-0">
      <div className="relative">
        <NavLink to="/">
        <AiOutlineArrowLeft
          className="absolute top-0 right-5 h-16 w-16 text-white cursor-pointer hidden md:block"
          // onClick={backToTiles}
        />
      </NavLink>
      </div>
      <img src={state.from.cover} alt="Cover" className="ml-0 md:ml-10" />
      <div className="flex ml-0 md:ml-10 mt-5 justify-start items-center">
        <AiOutlinePlayCircle
          className="h-16 w-16 text-white"
          // onClick= CLICKING PLAY HERE THE AUDIOPLAYER SHOULD PLAY THIS SPECIFIC PODCAST
        />
        <p className="text-3xl font-bold ml-3">#{state.from.title}</p>
      </div>
      <p className="w-full md:w-6/12 ml-0 md:ml-10 mt-5">{state.from.info}</p>
      {trackList ? (
        <div className="ml-0 md:ml-10 my-5">
          <p>Tracklist:</p>
          {state.from.trackList.map((track) => (
            <p>{track}</p>
          ))}
        </div>
      ) : null}
      {members ? (
        <div className="ml-0 md:ml-10 my-5">
          <p></p>
          {state.from.members.map((member) => (
            <p>{member}</p>
          ))}
        </div>
      ) : null}
      
    </div>
  );
};

export default Info;
```

I am wondering if i have to use a useContext hook to deal with the data on the info component.

Comment: It does look like you need to implement the Context API. I'd suggest having all the states, controls and data in the context and let the `AudioPlayer`, `Tiles`, and `Info` components consume the data through `useContext` hooks.